# Computer suffers thermal shutdown without first trying thermal throttling

Tags: cpu, temperature

My laptop has an i7-4710MQ processor and a Nividea GeForce GTX 970m inside.

Recently I have noticed it performs unexpected, thermal shutdowns during gaming. It does not appear as though either the CPU or GPU are self-throttling in order to keep the temperatures down under load as most systems do.

Is there any way to rectify this?

Comment: If you are experiencing thermal shutdowns, then its overheating, and thus the CPU would be throttling itself before that happened.  A shutdown due to a thermal problem cannot happen before the CPU throttles itself in attempt to cool itself off.

Comment: This is exactly the problem though, no throttling seems to be occurring, everything runs fine up until the moment of shutdown. Is there any way to test if throttling is actually occurring?

Comment: You should first verify the temperatures before the system shutdown, without that information, you might be barking at the wrong tree.

Comment: I have, they tend to be hovering just below my TJmax of 100C just before shutdown.

Comment: Apply fresh thermal paste on the CPU and GPU heat sinks

Comment: Oh yay... trying to get to this CPU should be fun, but probably a good idea. Thanks

Comment: @Ramhound, *if* thermal shutdown would not happen without the CPU first throttling itself, then how can thermal paste help? (Not saying you're wrong; just asking.)

Comment: If it's overheating then thermal paste might help, if you don't try it, then you have a bigger problem

Answer (score 0):

is almost sure that your cpu or gpu is overheating. and I suppose this is because of the curtain of dust which block you radiator.

with laptop on and ACTIVE fan you have to blow strongly the radiator, do it like you sneeze. if you do this when the fan is NOT working you have big chances to block it with that curtain of dust.

Comment: It's not dust, I clean it frequently...